# iOS keyboard with numbers and text only

Tags: swift, ios8

I want to have a keyboard similar to this one:
[image]

So, just numbers at the first row and letter below.. Is there an easy way to do this in iOS 8? None of the UIKeyboardType seems to have this structure.

Comment: "Is there an easy way to do this" What is "easy" in your opinion?

Comment: Not making my custom keyboard :)

Comment: Then there is no easy way. You said it yourself: none of the built-in keyboards looks like this. The End.

Answer (score 1):

There is one easy way to achieve that is you have to make custom keyboard for it because there is no built in keyboard available as you want. so download this [tasty-imitation-keyboard](https://github.com/archagon/tasty-imitation-keyboard). And you can modify its code into `DefaultKeyboard.swift`as given below:

```
func defaultKeyboard() -> Keyboard {
    var defaultKeyboard = Keyboard()

    // add this row at index 0.
    for key in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"] {
        var keyModel = Key(.Character)
        keyModel.setLetter(key)
        defaultKeyboard.addKey(keyModel, row: 0, page: 0)
    }

    for key in ["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P"] {
        var keyModel = Key(.Character)
        keyModel.setLetter(key)
        defaultKeyboard.addKey(keyModel, row: 1, page: 0)
    }

    for key in ["A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L"] {
        var keyModel = Key(.Character)
        keyModel.setLetter(key)
        defaultKeyboard.addKey(keyModel, row: 2, page: 0)
    }

    var keyModel = Key(.Shift)
    defaultKeyboard.addKey(keyModel, row: 3, page: 0)

    for key in ["Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M"] {
        var keyModel = Key(.Character)
        keyModel.setLetter(key)
        defaultKeyboard.addKey(keyModel, row: 3, page: 0)
    }

    var backspace = Key(.Backspace)
    defaultKeyboard.addKey(backspace, row: 3, page: 0)

    var keyModeChangeNumbers = Key(.ModeChange)
    keyModeChangeNumbers.uppercaseKeyCap = "123"
    keyModeChangeNumbers.toMode = 1
    defaultKeyboard.addKey(keyModeChangeNumbers, row: 4, page: 0)

    var keyboardChange = Key(.KeyboardChange)
    defaultKeyboard.addKey(keyboardChange, row: 4, page: 0)

    var settings = Key(.Settings)
    defaultKeyboard.addKey(settings, row: 4, page: 0)

    var space = Key(.Space)
    space.uppercaseKeyCap = "space"
    space.uppercaseOutput = " "
    space.lowercaseOutput = " "
    defaultKeyboard.addKey(space, row: 4, page: 0)

    var returnKey = Key(.Return)
    returnKey.uppercaseKeyCap = "return"
    returnKey.uppercaseOutput = "\n"
    returnKey.lowercaseOutput = "\n"
    defaultKeyboard.addKey(returnKey, row: 4, page: 0)

    for key in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"] {
        var keyModel = Key(.SpecialCharacter)
        keyModel.setLetter(key)
        defaultKeyboard.addKey(keyModel, row: 0, page: 1)
    }

    for key in ["-", "/", ":", ";", "(", ")", "$", "&", "@", "\""] {
        var keyModel = Key(.SpecialCharacter)
        keyModel.setLetter(key)
        defaultKeyboard.addKey(keyModel, row: 1, page: 1)
    }

    var keyModeChangeSpecialCharacters = Key(.ModeChange)
    keyModeChangeSpecialCharacters.uppercaseKeyCap = "#+="
    keyModeChangeSpecialCharacters.toMode = 2
    defaultKeyboard.addKey(keyModeChangeSpecialCharacters, row: 2, page: 1)

    for key in [".", ",", "?", "!", "'"] {
        var keyModel = Key(.SpecialCharacter)
        keyModel.setLetter(key)
        defaultKeyboard.addKey(keyModel, row: 2, page: 1)
    }

    defaultKeyboard.addKey(Key(backspace), row: 2, page: 1)

    var keyModeChangeLetters = Key(.ModeChange)
    keyModeChangeLetters.uppercaseKeyCap = "ABC"
    keyModeChangeLetters.toMode = 0
    defaultKeyboard.addKey(keyModeChangeLetters, row: 3, page: 1)

    defaultKeyboard.addKey(Key(keyboardChange), row: 3, page: 1)

    defaultKeyboard.addKey(Key(settings), row: 3, page: 1)

    defaultKeyboard.addKey(Key(space), row: 3, page: 1)

    defaultKeyboard.addKey(Key(returnKey), row: 3, page: 1)

    for key in ["[", "]", "{", "}", "#", "%", "^", "*", "+", "="] {
        var keyModel = Key(.SpecialCharacter)
        keyModel.setLetter(key)
        defaultKeyboard.addKey(keyModel, row: 0, page: 2)
    }

    for key in ["_", "\\", "|", "~", "<", ">", "€", "£", "¥", "•"] {
        var keyModel = Key(.SpecialCharacter)
        keyModel.setLetter(key)
        defaultKeyboard.addKey(keyModel, row: 1, page: 2)
    }

    defaultKeyboard.addKey(Key(keyModeChangeNumbers), row: 2, page: 2)

    for key in [".", ",", "?", "!", "'"] {
        var keyModel = Key(.SpecialCharacter)
        keyModel.setLetter(key)
        defaultKeyboard.addKey(keyModel, row: 2, page: 2)
    }

    defaultKeyboard.addKey(Key(backspace), row: 2, page: 2)

    defaultKeyboard.addKey(Key(keyModeChangeLetters), row: 3, page: 2)

    defaultKeyboard.addKey(Key(keyboardChange), row: 3, page: 2)

    defaultKeyboard.addKey(Key(settings), row: 3, page: 2)

    defaultKeyboard.addKey(Key(space), row: 3, page: 2)

    defaultKeyboard.addKey(Key(returnKey), row: 3, page: 2)

    return defaultKeyboard
}
```

And your result will be:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just go in interface builder and select the text field(or the object that wants a keybord)and in attributes inspector under Text Field(if it is text field).You can find keyboard type and select what you want(ex :number pad ,decimal pad,numbers and punctuation ).

Comment: Nope. None of the options have the same appearance with the picture in the question. Thanks.